# How to animate strokeDashOffset in Adobe XD?

Tags: javascript, plugins, adobe-xd

In Adobe XD, I have a *dashed* Path (or Line) that I need to animate.  In other software, I've always done this by animating the path's dash offset (its "phase").  In Adobe XD, this property exists but is not exposed through the user interface.

I've done some digging and found in the plugin API that [Line](https://adobexdplatform.com/plugin-docs/reference/scenegraph.html#line) and [Path](https://adobexdplatform.com/plugin-docs/reference/scenegraph.html#path) derive from [GraphicNode](https://adobexdplatform.com/plugin-docs/reference/scenegraph.html#GraphicNode), and that they both have a [strokeDashOffset](https://adobexdplatform.com/plugin-docs/reference/scenegraph.html#line) property.

I've made a quick plugin that prints and sets these values, using something along the lines of:

```js
function animateLineDashCommand(selection) {
    let linesAndPaths = selection.items.filter(el => el instanceof Path || el instanceof Line);

    linesAndPaths.forEach(el => {
        el.strokeDashOffset = 10; // Or whatever test value I'm using.
    });
}
```

This works just fine, and the path definitely changes its phase.  However, if I place the same line on two different Artboards with different phases, then wire them together using Auto Animate, the property is ignored.  I'm assuming that behind the scenes, this property isn't interpolated.

Does anybody know of a way to have this property animate and/or an alternative solution to path offset animation in Adobe XD?  To my knowledge, animated SVGs or [GIFs](https://adobexd.uservoice.com/forums/353007-adobe-xd-feature-requests/suggestions/12924336-import-videos-animated-gifs-to-show-in-interacti) are not currently possible.

Thanks.

**Update 1:**
I have tried a manual frame-by-frase approach inside of a Component, where each state is essentially a frame with a different dash phase.  The idea was to make the Component a contained timeline so that the animation could be reused in different Artboards.  However, Components do not support the `Time` trigger, which means it can only be forwarded by an interaction (clicking, dragging, etc).  This approach will not work.

**Update 2:**
Since Artboards do have access to the `Time` trigger, I can duplicate the Artboards as many times as I need frames, and have each containing path have its dash phase set accordingly.  This works **but** is quite painful as it can require a large quantity of duplicated Artboards, which I want to avoid.  There is also a performance penalty for animating between dense Artboards quickly.

I have made a quick GUI plugin to make this easier and [uploaded it to GitHub](https://github.com/KasumiL5x/xd-animate-line-dash).  I'll keep this question open in case a better solution is found.